# convert epoch time into dd/mm/yy in a file

Tags: linux, date, unix, epoch

In a file I have `n` number of epoch times.

I have to convert the each epoch time into dd/mm/yy format.

eg: file1 content:

```
1 aaa 1322625862.408 
2 bbb 1322625848.954
3 ccc 1322625843.908
4 ddd 1322625865.436
```

Now I want to convert this epoch time.

Comment: Clarify how your output should look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easier to just use `read` with dummy parameters and fetching just the ones you want:

```
while read _ _ epoch
do
   date -d@"$epoch" "+%d/%m/%y"
done < file
```

This way, the third word of every line gets stored into `$epoch`. Then, you use `date -d@XXX` to convert epoch to normal timestamp. Remember you can set a format using `"+%Y%m..."` and things like that.

#### Test

```
$ while read _ _ epoch; do date -d@$epoch "+%d/%m/%y"; done < a
30/11/11
30/11/11
30/11/11
30/11/11
```

Comment: Nice. Never thought of doing stuff this way.

Comment: why are you using  read _ _ epoch??

Comment: @Jaquelinefernadas because their value is not necessary, we just need `$epoch`.

Comment: @Jaquelinefernadas `_` is commonly used to note "I don't care about this value"

Answer (score 1):

you can use `date`:

```
reut@EliteBook-8470p:~/$ for epoch in $(cat f.txt | cut -d' ' -f 3); do date -d @$epoch +%d/%m/%y; done
```

Pipeline walkthourgh:

`$(cat f.txt | cut -d' ' -f 3)` takes each 3rd column in every line split by `' '` as dlimiter. This is the epoch string you have.

Now use each of these (using a `for` loop) as an argument to `date -d @<eopch>` and set the format to `%d/%m/%y`.

Output:

```
30/11/11
30/11/11
30/11/11
30/11/11
```

**Edit:** To actually store this in a result file:

```
while read serial name tdate; do echo ${serial} ${name} $(date -d@"${tdate}" "+%d/%m/%y") >> result_file; done < your_file.txt
```

Now your output is in result file.

Output in `result_file`:

```
1 aaa 30/11/11
2 bbb 30/11/11
3 ccc 30/11/11
4 ddd 30/11/11
```

Thanks @fedorqui.

Comment: I have to store the date again in that file in the serial number, name , date format..

Comment: @Jaquelinefernadas see edits

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify but I believe you need Linux command.
If you want to parse it from file just do:

```
for i in `awk '{print $2}' kuku `; do
date -d @$i +"%d/%m/%y"
done
```

it just takes from the file the relevant column with timestamp, and execute
date -d @ +"%d/%m/%y"

output:

```
30/11/11
30/11/11
30/11/11
30/11/11
```

Hope it help a bit